# How to get width and height of a div with extjs 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How to get width and height of a div with extjs 4?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Ext.get("divid").getWidth();  // Width 
    Ext.get("divid").getHeight(); // Height
```

Comment: thanks a lot i was trying with div class and got error with div id its working fine